How to pre-populate a form field with model's foreignkey field's value at form load in Django
I have the following models:
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='member/', null=True, blank=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

I have created model form, generic views for creating and updating the Member class.
From here, I want to be able to upload members' photos to the second model 'Photo' directly from the ListView for "Member", by adding a link to the CreateView for uploading the photo.
The ModelForm and CreateView for adding the photos are:
ModelForm
class MemberPhotoAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('member', 'member_photo')
        widgets = {
            'member': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type name...', }),
            'member_photo': forms.FileInput(attrs={'onchange': 'readURL(this)'}),
            }

CreateView
class PhotoUpload(CreateView):
    template_name = "member_photo_add.html"
    model = Photo
    form_class = MemberPhotoAddForm

    success_url = reverse_lazy('member_list') # URL for the ListView for Member class

    # I am trying to use method 'get_inital()' to pass 'member_id' to the form to add a 'Photo'
    def get_initial(self):
        member = self.request.GET.get('Member')
        return {
            'member': member,
            }

In urls.py, I have:
    ...
    path('member_acct/photos/add/<int:pk>', views.PhotoUpload.as_view(), name='member_photo_add'),
    ...

In my template I am traversing thru' the fields in order to display the fields (and their values).
However, as I am intending to do, I am unable to populate the member's primary key value, when the form is loaded (for adding photo) - the field remains blank.
(In a post on SO I have read some poster telling to the effect that

manually go through all the fields you might be not displaying the initial value

But resorting to using the plain form.as_p also did not help.
Is what I am trying to is the right way? Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Are you trying to populate the CreateView form with model data?  or are you having trouble displaying the created object in the member_list view?

Sorry if I have not been clear. What I want to do is: 1. User to click on a link in the ListView displaying the objects as already created in the Member model, thru' the URL ... member_photo_add. 2. The link is intended to take the user to the form displaying the Member fields as well as the member_photo (as in the CreateView PhotoUpload), which will be used to select the photo and finally save it. Thanks.

Solved it by modifying the CreateView this way:
def get_initial(self):
    member = self.kwargs['pk']    # << Here
    return {
        'member': member,
        }

With help from Mr. Roseman
